# Best Way To Create C# Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation

I use Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.  I would like to be able to create an installer for a project I have.  I can kind of do it with the Publish tool, but you get little to no control.

Is there a free way to do this, or do I need to spring for the full-blown version of VS2008?
-or-
Do I just not know what I am doing when publishing?

My biggest issue is that it doesn't let the user choose where to install the program, it just drops it in some predefined location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not need to use MSI, you could use the Nullsoft Scriptable Install System. It is free and is the installer used by a lot of open source programs.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't need to pay for the full Visual Studio, but it might be easier.

- You can try to write Wix code in a text editor.  It's complicated though, and will require some reading to understand the Wix/MSI model. [Download the wix tools](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). [Read the MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163456.aspx).
- there is IExpress, built-in to Windows. Run it from c:\windows\system32\iexpress.exe . It will create an EXE installer for you. It's not MSI based.
- Try InnoSetup for an open-source tool that builds MSI installers for Windows.
- Finally, there is the option to use a self-extracting ZIP file.  [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) is a free .NET library that allows you to create a self-extracting EXE.   When run, it extracts the files and then optionally runs an application afterwards.  The app could be something you write (and extract), or it could be a simple cmd.exe command line.

Comment: +1 for WiX, which is actually pretty easy to use (granted, with standard VS or higher).  There is also an app called WarSetup which makes creating WiX Installers even easier: http://warsetup.jgaa.com/

Comment: IExpress is great for creating a simple file installer, and you can set options such as the target installation directory using command line options: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496369.aspx

Comment: Good helpful comment, but InnoSetup does not build MSI installers, rather .EXE installers.

Answer (score 3):

[Nullsoft Installer System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is pretty mature, flexible and powerful.  I think it would meet your requirements.

Comment: hi, can you please share a good tutorial for this...i've searched a lot but couldn't find anything